# What is the best way to override a JsonConvertor Default Settings in one method

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Let's say I have got a service where I got following default settings for JsonSerializerSettings.

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Formatting = Formatting.None,
                Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()},
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
            };
```

This value for DateParseHandling has to be changed for one of the method call which calls an external dll. Even though the method returns a model itself, for some reason it takes the local default setting for our service.

While debugging we found that the method needs to have following setting ,

```
DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime
```

So the only thing we could make it work or an ugly hack was that resetting the DefaultSettings to,

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime
        };
```

However this code will overwrite the current default setting, Which we do not want to do. Also if we had JsonString we could have used like this,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Twin>(jsontext, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime});
```

which is not an option at the moment.

**Additional Details**

The external method uses a converter : TwinJsonConvertor ([Link to Git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/shared/src/TwinJsonConverter.cs))

Any idea what is the best way to override the default settings for just one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have problems with concurrency you could do something similar to this:

```
public static boolean ativateSpecialDateSerialization = false;

JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

    if (ativateSpecialDateSerialization)
    {
        // Special date parsing settings
        settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime     
    }
    else
    {
        // Default settings
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.None,
        settings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()},
        settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
    }

    return settings;
};


try
{
    ativateSpecialDateSerialization = true;

    // Call to your extrernal method
}
finally
{
    ativateSpecialDateSerialization = false;
}
```

You could also improve the code by preserving both `JsonSerializerSettings` objects.

Comment: We do have some issues with the concurrency though. But thanks for the solution